# insufficient funds for gas * price + value using geth --dev

Tags: ethereum, solidity, geth

I keep getting an error deploying a smart contract (using netheruem). The error is: insufficient funds for gas * price + value with geth command:

```
geth --dev --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" console
```

I read that I need to adjust the gas limit in my genesis.json file but I have done this step before I init the geth. Here is my genesis.json file:

```
{
"config":{
   "chainId": 45,
   "homesteadBlock": 0,
   "eip155Block": 0,
   "eip158Block": 0,
   "byzantiumBlock": 12
},
"alloc" : {},
"coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData" : "",
"gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00"
}
```

My gas limit in my latest block is 6283185 which should be enough to deploy the smart contract. Is there something I need to check with the configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have enough funds in your deploying wallet to cover the cost of the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either supply funds to your account that is executing the transactions, or allow for 0 gas price transactions.

To fund an account, add the allocation to your genesis.json when creating the initial block:

```
{
   ...
   "alloc": {
        "ACCOUNT_ADDRESS": {
            "balance": "9999999999999999999999999"
        }
    }
}
```

Create the account through `geth` then use that address in the configuration. The value is in Wei.

In lieu of using funds, you can use a gas price set to 0, but you’ll have to start your miner(s) with the `—gasPrice` set to 0 (otherwise, your miners will ignore your transactions). Even if you use 0 gas prices, you still have gas limit constraints.